# window.open within setTimeout doesn't perform the action

Tags: javascript

Why does this call to setTimeout show the alert box but does not do the call to window.open?
If I remove the alert, it doesn't do the window.open either.

```
    // Pause first then open window
    function pause_first (url) {
        alert (url);
        var external_window = window.open(url,'_blank'); 
        external_window.focus();
    }

    var pause_ret = setTimeout( function() { pause_first(url); }, 1000);
```

Comment: Browsers don't open popups unless it's as a response to a user action such as `"click"`

Comment: Is there a different way to delay a window.open?

Comment: I was having the same problem with an app I'm making. It's good to know that the browser blocks it and I'm not just stupid, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, because your browser considers it to be a non-user-triggered popup … so it blocks it.

Comment: So if I call that setTimeout within a function called in the onclick event of an element somewhere the browser thinks that it's not a user action anymore?  Is there a way to make the browser think that it is?