# setTimeout window.open does not wait, how can I solve this?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

The code:

```
function overlay() {
    el = document.getElementById("overlay");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}

function win_open(URL) {
  window.open(URL, "_blank");
}

function link_redirect(linkaddress) {
  // display message
  {
    overlay();

    setTimeout(function() {overlay();
    }, 2000);

    setTimeout(win_open(linkaddress), 2000);
  }

  //return false;
}
```

The problem is that the window opens but there is no delay. I have also tried:

```
setTimeout(function() {win_open(linkaddress);}, 2000);
```

but no.

What I want to achieve is that when `link_redirect(linkaddress)` is ran, it displays immediately the overlay, waits 2 secs, hides the overlay and shows the window from the given url in `_blank`.

Comment: "[Hurry]" - Oh rly? Nah, no question is "urgent" on Stack Overflow. If it really was, you would be trying to solve it yourself right now.

Comment: I have discovered a truly marvelous solution of this, which [Hurry] tag is too offensive to answer.

Comment: `setTimeout(function(){window.open()}, 20000);` This is working for me in Firebug..

Comment: Yes, but window.open() has to pass the argument. That seems to be causing the problems.

Comment: Seems to be that Safari doesn't like the solution. Firefox is fine like you said.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in your second `setTimeout` call, you are invoking the function `win_open` then passing the value returned by it to `setTimeout` as the callback

You need

```
function link_redirect(linkaddress) {
    overlay();

    setTimeout(function() {
        overlay();
        win_open(linkaddress)
    }, 2000);
    //return false;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is basically eliminating the second setTimeout() but for some reason when win_open(linkaddress) is run like you wrote it, it won't trigger. The overlay() triggers in your example but win_open(linkaddress won't).

Comment: It feels like the argument is not getting passed to win_open().

Comment: looks like browser might be blocking it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047165/window-open-within-settimeout-doesnt-perform-the-action